# In Django Bootstrap 4, how to avoid rendering an alert with form errors?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-bootstrap4

I'm using `django-bootstrap4` (https://django-bootstrap4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in a project and find that when there are errors in a form, an alert box shows up with a list of the errors. In my case, this is problematic because the errors are repeated:

[image]

I've had a look at the `FormRenderer` source code, and I don't see a way I can opt out of displaying this 'alert of errors':

```
class FormRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    """
    Default form renderer
    """

    def __init__(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(form, BaseForm):
            raise BootstrapError(
                'Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form.')
        self.form = form
        super(FormRenderer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.error_css_class = kwargs.get('error_css_class', None)
        self.required_css_class = kwargs.get('required_css_class', None)
        self.bound_css_class = kwargs.get('bound_css_class', None)

    def render_fields(self):
        rendered_fields = []
        for field in self.form:
            rendered_fields.append(render_field(
                field,
                layout=self.layout,
                form_group_class=self.form_group_class,
                field_class=self.field_class,
                label_class=self.label_class,
                show_label=self.show_label,
                show_help=self.show_help,
                exclude=self.exclude,
                set_placeholder=self.set_placeholder,
                size=self.size,
                horizontal_label_class=self.horizontal_label_class,
                horizontal_field_class=self.horizontal_field_class,
                error_css_class=self.error_css_class,
                required_css_class=self.required_css_class,
                bound_css_class=self.bound_css_class,
            ))
        return '\n'.join(rendered_fields)

    def get_fields_errors(self):
        form_errors = []
        for field in self.form:
            if not field.is_hidden and field.errors:
                form_errors += field.errors
        return form_errors

    def render_errors(self, type='all'):
        form_errors = None
        if type == 'all':
            form_errors = self.get_fields_errors() + self.form.non_field_errors()
        elif type == 'fields':
            form_errors = self.get_fields_errors()
        elif type == 'non_fields':
            form_errors = self.form.non_field_errors()

        if form_errors:
            return render_template_file(
                'bootstrap4/form_errors.html',
                context={
                    'errors': form_errors,
                    'form': self.form,
                    'layout': self.layout,
                    'type': type,
                }
            )

        return ''

    def _render(self):
        return self.render_errors() + self.render_fields()
```

This is because the `_render()` method always shows both `self.render_errors()` and `self.render_fields()` (cf. https://github.com/zostera/django-bootstrap4/blob/ead5d4d06547b93aa49d40fac88c9de42fefda34/bootstrap4/renderers.py#L216-L217).

How do I prevent this repetition of errors (by disabling the alert box)?

Comment: For the time being, I've downgraded to `django-bootstrap3`, but this is less than ideal because I'm actually using Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Do you use `FormRenderer` directly? As a quick fix, you could create a subclass and override `_render()` to pass type="non_fields" to `render_errors()`. It kinda seems like something where the devs might appreciate a pull request though.